# How to call data from firebase synchronously

Tags: arrays, firebase, function, swiftui

I have a function that calls data from my Firebase Database, but it is an `async` function, and messing up the other functions of my app. I have looked all around tutorials but they only show asyncronus functions, and my app depends on the Firebase Data to load first.

Code for the function:

```
@State var realLat: [String] = [ ]
@State var realLong: [String] = [ ]

func downloadFirebaseData() async throws -> Float {
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()                // << start
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        try withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            db.collection("annotations")
                .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    defer {
                        group.leave()    // << end on any return
                    }
                    
                    // result heading code here
                    if let Lat = i.document.get("lat") as? String {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            realLat.append(Lat)
                            print("downloadLatServerData() \(realLat)")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        group.wait()   // << block till leave
    }
```

The function `DownloadFirebaseMapServerData()` is an async function becuase of the line `db.collection("annotations").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in...` and I **need** `realLat` and `realLong` to be downloaded first inorder to assign them to a `mapAnnotation`, so is there any way that I could make this function syncronus or make another function with the same end goal? Also another thing to note is that `realLat` and `realLong` are both String Arrays, or Arrays that are Strings

Comment: The closest thing is async await https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Comment: I think I got it, please check the updated code snippet. But I get the error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` on the line of `try withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in`

Comment: You should watch the video again, especially where they talk about converting, sequences and streams. I am sure there isn't a sample like this in that video. Who wrote that comment in the code? I am assuming this is either a school or work task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, let's say that - try to avoid making synchronous API that designed asynchronous - it was done by purpose, long time-consuming bla-bla-bla

but, if it is needed technically it is possible, for example using dispatch groups, like

```
func downloadFirebaseData() async throws -> Float {
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()                // << start

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        try withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            db.collection("annotations")
                .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

                    defer {
                       group.leave()    // << end on any return
                    }

                    // result heading code here
                }
        }
        group.wait()   // << block till leave
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation` if `continuation` is never called?

Comment: this does not answer the question: `How to call data from firebase synchronously`, despite the OP thinking it is the answer to his problems.